# Kendo-ui-angular2 Pie chart labels not displayed

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to build a pie chart in Kendo-ui-angular2. Pie chart is displayed but labels are not. Any live plunker or example is highly appreciated.

```
<kendo-chart>
            <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
            <kendo-chart-legend position="top" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
            <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
            <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                    type="donut" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>


  private series: any[] = [{
    name: ["India","Aus", "Fin"],
    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848]
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add :

```
<kendo-chart-series-defaults>
   <kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels [visible]="true" </kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels>
</kendo-chart-series-defaults>
```